# Minimum sum path in a 2D array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matrix

I was asked this problem during an interview -

We have 4 swimmers A,B,C,D with their records in 4 types of swimming races i.e Freestyle, Frontstroke , Backstroke and Butterffly respectively.The data is given as 4 arrays each for one player where each element in the array represents their time in particular race. 
We have to create a team of these players for a relay race such that the total time is minimum.

I was able to reduce this problem as below, which the interviewer accepted to be the correct approach to the above problem -

Given a 2D array find the minimum sum path such that from a particular element arr[i][j] we cannot select the next element in the same row as well as in the same column because we cannot select same player for more than 1 race & we cannot have more than 1 player in same race.

But,I was not able to develop a working algorithm for this problem.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In general, it's a min-cost maximum bipartite matching problem, but you have a small 4-4 graph and simple brute-force algorithm will be ok.

Comment: @DAle can you specify the brute-force algorithm for this. thanks

Comment: iterate through all 24 permutations of swimming races (columns in your matrix), for every permutation count the total time, select the best time among them.

Comment: You are looking for the *assignment problem* solution, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm